# Java reading multi line text file, add delimiter at the end of each line after final character

Tags: java, text, readline

I have the following text file. I am reading each line at a time and pushing the whole line into a String. Currently, my code just reads each line by line without concern for any spaces so

`random text` becomes `randomtext`. Is there a way to insert a space after the last character in the line? I have tried the following code and it does not do the job.

`d = d.replaceAll("\n", " ");`

Textfile.txt

```
Text random text random numbers etc. This is a random
text file.
```

Comment: How are you reading the lines?

Answer (score 5):

After you read the lines in, there isn't any '\n' character in your string. So, what you need to do is to join these lines by space. Just use `String.join()`

In Java 8, all you need is:

```
File f = new File("your file path");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
String result = String.join(" ", lines);
```

**UPDATE**

As Shire pointed out in the comment below, if the file is of huge size, it's better to use a buffered reader to read each line in and concatenate them with a space.

Here is how to use a `BufferredReader`

```
File file = new File("file_path");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append(" ");
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: If the file has too many lines it would be better to use a BufferedReader to read a line at a time and build the string in a StringBuilder appending a space ' ' after each line except the last.

Comment: @ShireResident yes, I agree. I will include that in the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there are better ways, like the first answer.  I suggest another way using **Java 8**.  This may not be a perfect solution - just another way to solve a problem.  I use similar blocks as below:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```

Then, build a `StringBuilder` to extract the file contents as a full string including lines.

```
final StringBuilderWriter writer = new StringBuilderWriter();
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        writer.append("exception", e));
    }
    return writer.toString();
```

And then, apply `.split(\n)` on the returned string above.

Further more, to iterate each line from the split string:

```
Arrays.asList(string).split("\n"))
```